# Need help creating a GET route

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need help implement a route to fetch all blog posts by author_ids.

- The post that we're fetching needs to have at least one of the authors specified in the passed in author_ids parameters. I've created a helper function to help me fetch all blog posts by their ID, `Post.get_posts_by_user_id`
- I also need to sort the posts by query parameters given. Also, I need to delete any duplicated posts as efficiently as possible.

I'm stumped here because of the way `author_ids` is being given. (I'm extremely new to Ruby)

This is what we should get returned from the route: `"posts": [{"id": 1, "likes": 960, "popularity": 0.13, "reads": 50361, "tags": ["tech", "health"], text": "Some text here."}, ... ]`

[Query parameters expected to be given to this route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzOoS.png)

***Update:***

After creating the index method, it seems that it is only getting one post rather than getting all posts that are associated with the passed in `authorIds`.

```
def index
  posts = current_user
  .posts
  .where(id: params[:authorIds].split(','))
  .order(sort_column => sort_direction)

  if posts
    render json: { post: posts }, status: :ok
  else
    render json: {error: posts.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

[Test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCihm.png)

***Update 2***:

Post Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord


# Associations
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :users, through: :user_posts, dependent: :destroy

  # Validations
  validates :text, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
  validates :popularity, inclusion: { in: 0.0..1.0 }

  def tags
    if super
      super.split(",")
    end
  end

  def tags=(value)
    if value.kind_of? Array
      super value.join(",")
    else
      super value
    end
  end

  def self.get_posts_by_user_id(user_id)
    Post.joins(:user_posts).where(user_posts: { user_id: user_id })
  end
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  # Associations
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :posts, through: :user_posts, dependent: :destroy

  # Validations
  validates :username, :password, presence: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :username, uniqueness: true
end
```

User_post Model:

```
class UserPost < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: Please share the code you already wrote. What exactly is your problem? To define the route in the routes.rb? Or to write the method in the controller?

Comment: I have not written any code yet, honestly don't have the confidence to start. I just need to write the method in the controller, my bad for not being specific. RoR is quite unique compared to the technologies I usually program in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like below.

```
def index
  author_ids_array = params[:ids].to_s.split(',')

  Post
    .get_posts_by_user_id(author_ids_array)
    .order(sort_column => sort_direction)
end

private

def sort_column
  allow_list = %w[id reads likes popularity]
  params[:sortBy].presence_in(allow_list) || allow_list.first
end

def sort_direction
  allow_list = %w[asc desc]
  params[:direction].presence_in(allow_list) || allow_list.first
end
```

Comment: I added an update to the posting. Is it possible that the where clause is only getting the first id in the authorIds passed in?

Comment: I do not have an author_id column, I would if I could. Unfortunately I am not allowed to change any of those files. It is 3 models, User, Post, and user_posts. The method I mentioned above in the first bullet allows me to grab the posts that exist by that author. I updated the original post. Sorry, If I am not making too much sense as this is all really new to me.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the `get_posts_by_user_id` that already exists in your application.

Comment: Since the `get_posts_by_user_id` only takes in one id at a time, does this mean I will have to do a loop through the `author_ids_array` and pass the individual elements in to this method?

Comment: `Post.joins(:user_posts).where(user_posts: { user_id: user_id })` actually works with an array of ids too. See [3.3.3 Subset Conditions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions) in the Rails Guides

Comment: That is a really cool feature, did not know that. Thank you for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: I got feedback from some more unit tests and apparently the `index` method does not fetch posts that multiple authors. Any ideas? I thought that sending the array would return all associated posts. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple authors"? Doesn't it fetch any post with multiple authors? I would be surprised if that was the case. Or do you want to fetch only posts that have the exact authors given by the `author_ids`? That would indeed require a different approach. It would be worth a new question because that is a different use case than your current question.

Comment: Fetch any posts that belong to an author within `author_ids`. So, if we're given an array like `[1,3,5]` we want to fetch ALL of author's 1,3, and 5 blog posts. It is possible that when doing that, there can be duplicates. Thus, I must figure out a way to get rid of duplicates. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: Okay, got it. You can simply add [`.distinct`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct) to your query when you want to avoid duplicate records that happen because of the database join.